# SQL server linked server to catalog of documents in Windows Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, search, indexing, service, linked-server

I have a legacy web app that is able to provide search results (a list of documents) from strings that are contained within those documents.

This was achieved by:

1. Using MS Indexing Service to index a folder of documents and store the results in a catalog file.
2. Creating a Linked SQL server instance to that catalog file.
3. Querying the linked SQL server database from the web app and returning a list of file names.

I need to move this application to Windows Server 2012 or later. The problem is that (as far as I am aware) Indexing Service is obsolete and was replaced by Windows Search.

What I need to know is can I do the same with with a linked SQL server to Windows Search?

Comment: Isn't it way easier to just interface the Windows Search from the web app using it's SDK?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965362(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Probably, but that mean rebuilding the app instead of just moving it to the new server.